How to rename file from outlook attachment with information from the body the email
I am using this script to download an attached pdf from an email in outlook and change the name of the file with info from the subject line.  I need to change from pulling the info from the subject to pulling info from the body of email.
Here is body of email, I need the number in the CID and the CSID line added to file name:
Delivery Information: 
Message #:      1038881482

Local Number:       2395942222
Remote CSID:        2394362222
Remote CID:         2394362233
Total Pages:        1

Receive Time:       7/9/2024 7:01:39 AM EDT
Transmit Time:      0.027 sec

Here is the script I am currently using:
Sub OfcsaveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String

saveFolder = "C:\Data\Nextiva\"

strsubject = Split(itm.Subject)(2)

   For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & strsubject & "-" & "OFC-" & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub

Ive tried using Right(InStrRev(itm.Body))  but cant get it to work.

This question is similar to: Search structured text in Outlook body. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
